# Corrupted command prompt causing memory leak

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, memory-leaks

I am running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. RAM is 4 GB.

When I type in a command into the command prompt like `dir` or run a script like
    `ruby my_script.rb`, the command prompt window stops responding. In Task Manager -> Performance, the memory is rapidly getting filled up & CPU hits close to 100% and overall system becomes unresponsive.

When I close the window by pressing the close button, the text `^C` keeps getting printed on the screen before it closes eventually..

I scanned my system with an anti-virus and it didn't detect any virus.

Is there a way to fix this? I tried getting cmd.exe from another Win 7 pro 64-bit machine & tried to replace my cmd.exe but it looks like I can't do it while windows is running.

Thank you.

Comment: Get your install disk and boot from it, run a repair. You'll almost certainly have to re-download and apply a ton of updates after that, but it will be worth it.

Comment: I'll have to search for my Windows Installation disc. Looks like something to do over the weekend.

Would it by any chance wipe my hard disk or just would scan for damaged files & replace them?

Comment: Is everything you are trying to do in cmd local?  I might expect a mapped network drive to behave this way given enough flakiness.  Can you remember if anything weird happened before you noticed the behaviour starting?

Comment: It's not on a network. It's my personal laptop and it's not networked. I don't exactly remember after what this happened, but I suspect cygwin has something to do with it. I had installed cygwin and uninstalled it in a few days. I am not 100% sure as this could be coincidental too.

Comment: It shouldn't wipe your drive, no. If things are that bad though, burn a boot CD of whatever OS you want and boot from it, then copy the contents of your hard drive somewhere else first, just to be safe.

Comment: Ok. I will try this out & see if it fixes the issue. Thanks.